# Vuejs JSX onTouchStart is not recognized

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jsx

I'm trying to use JSX with Vuejs and currently I try to do this

```
export default {
  methods: {
    handleClick: function (e) {
      console.log('clicking: ', e)
    },
    handleTouchStart: function (e) {
      console.log('touching: ', e)
    }
  },
  render (h) {
    return (
      <div
        className="slider"
        onTouchStart={(e) => this.handleTouchStart(e)}
        onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
        <h1> Hey there </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The `handleTouchStart` function is not called, but we can still see `handleClick` is called while clicking the element. I'm not sure how many Synthetic events are supported in Vue JSX syntax ?

Do we need any other library to let Vue know about `touch` events ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I found that `onTouchStart`, `onTouchMove`, `onTouchEnd` are mapped like `onTouchstart`, `onTouchmove` and `onTouchend`. Not sure why it's like that only first letter after `on` is capitalized as JSX should support camel case syntax. Anyway replacing with above events, it correctly detects the event names.